# While using haxe-react it renders String instead of Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, haxe

I am trying to render a list component using Haxe and haxe-react. But it renders the '' as string in HTML! Any directions. Here is the code for it.

```
  override public function render(){
  var sList:String = this.getListString();

  return jsx('
    <div style={{margin:"10px", border:"black 2px solid"}}>
     ${ sList }
    </div>
  ');
}
private function getListString():String{
  var result:String = '';
  for (i in 0 ... 10) {
    result += ('<div>'+i+'</div>');
  }
  return ('<div style={{margin:"10px", border:"black 2px solid"}}>'+result+'</div>');
}
```

While it compiles fine. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind. I figured out. The fix is to pass on an array of jsx rather than strings. 

The code is as below

Comment: override public function render(){
    var aList = this.getListArray();
    return jsx('
      <div style={{margin:"10px", border:"black 2px solid"}}>
          <h3>ViewList</h3>
          ${/* aList */}
      </div>
    ');
  }
  private function getListArray(){
    var aResult = [];
    for (i in 0 ... 10) {
      aResult.push( jsx('<div style={{margin:"10px", border:"#6666FF 1px solid"}}>${/* i */}</div>') );
    }
    return aResult;
  }

Comment: Yep :)


You will get a runtime warning about keys though, you might need to add something like key=$i in the div created in your for loop.

Comment: Thanks @kLabz for the tip :) 

Well, now "How to close this question!" I can not answer myself thats what SO says to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason, as the question author figured, is that the `jsx` macro does not process a `String` so you can't build it using concatenation: the macro transforms at compile time the parameter of `jsx('JSX expression')` into React Elements.

The right way to build a list of React Elements is to build an `Array<ReactElement>`:

```
private function getList() {
  var result = [];
  for (i in 0 ... 10) {
    result.push( jsx('<div key=$i>$i</div>') );
  }
  return jsx('<div style={{margin:"10px", border:"black 2px solid"}}>$result</div>');
}
```

PS: notice the added `key` attribute, it's important to specify a key to elements in an Array of ReactElements.